# How to transfer vector into function

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, variable-assignment

I have the following code:

```
void func(char *vChar);

int main(void){
    std::vector<char*> vChar;
    vChar.push_back("Bla Bla Bla");

    func(vChar);
    return 0;
}

void func(char *vChar){
    std::cout << vChar->size;
}
```

I dont know, it says i cant convert vector to char*. I ask then, what type is vChar? is it the same as char* in int tab[] (i mean tab is int*)?

Comment: In your code, 'func' accepts char *vChar - it needs to be vector<const char*>& vChar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a vector, give your function a parameter that is either a vector or a reference to vector:

```
void func(const vector<const char*>& vChar); // const ref if you won't modify it
```

Note that string literals should not be bound to non-const references (this is deprecated in C++11 for good reason), so make the vector a `vector<const char*>`, or `vector<string>` if you want it to own the data.

Comment: why is it not recomended in c++11? why i should use at least const char*?

Comment: @Babbaddo It's not just not recommended - it's deprecated. You can't do it. You never really should have been able to do it in the first place. The problem is that string literals are stored in a read-only section of memory. You shouldn't be able to modify the characters in them. However, a `char*` would let you, with terrible consequences.